# Find the initial movement of a particle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

A particle with mass $m$ is moving along a curve and the force exerted on it always points towards the origin, and it´s magnitude is proportional to the distance between the particle and the origin, with the initial condition that: $\vec r(0)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $\vec  r´(0)=\vec v_0$. a) Find the trajectory of the particle and b) How does the movement of the particle should have started so that the trajectory would be a circumference of radius $r>0$ around the origin?

I´m having trouble with question b). For the first question:

$\vec F=-k||\vec r(t)||\vec u$ where $\vec u$ is a unit vector that points towards the origin hence: $\vec u= {{\vec r(t)}\over {||r(t)||}}$ $$m {{d^2\vec r(t)}\over {dt^2}}=-k\vec r(t)$$ we have 3 differential equations:

$$m {{d^2x(t)}\over {dt^2}}=-kx(t)$$ and the corresponding equations with $y(t)$ and $z(t)$. Solving each one we obtain:

$$\begin{cases} x(t)=A_1sin(\omega t + \alpha_1) \\ y(t)=A_2sin(\omega t + \alpha_2) \\ z(t)=A_3sin(\omega t + \alpha_3) \end{cases}$$

where $\omega = \sqrt{k/m}$ and $A_1,A_2,A_3,\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ are constants determined by the initial conditions of the problem.

Can you please help me with the question b)? I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Note that, since the problem is rotationally symmetric, you're free to choose the initial position to be along the $x$-axis i.e. $\vec{r}(0)=(r,0,0).$ Then you just need to pick $\vec{v}_0$ so that the particle stays on that circle in the plane...(there's only one possible direction that can point!)

Comment: thanks a lot @Semiclassical :)